# Paying respects to Lord Ganesha

Tags: ganesha, shloka

I try to repeat the shloka in the rhythm of my breath and I find that always saying "om ganeshaya namaha" before the shloka breaks the rhythm.

Comment: I prefer this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVf-1eaXgRs&t=221s

Comment: Which sloka are you chanting? Also what is your question here?

Comment: I chant a shloka for Brihaspati (devanam ca rishinam...). I want to know if I have to think "om ganeshaya namaha" every time before I repeat the shloka.